# Exponential and Logarithmic Functions $\log_3 (x+7) - \log_3 (x-7) = 3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Having trouble solving this problem. Where have I gone wrong?

$$\log_3 (x+7) - \log_3 (x-7) = 3$$

$$\log_3 \left(\frac{x+7}{x-7}\right) = 3$$

$$\frac{x+7}{x-7} = 27$$

$$x+7 = 27 (x-7)$$

$$x + 7 = 27 x - 189$$

$$26 x = 196$$

$$x = \frac{196}{26} \approx 7.538$$

Comment: um nothing?????

Comment: It doesn't look like anything's wrong... [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Log%5Bx%2B7%5D%2FLog%5B3%5D+-+Log%5Bx-7%5D%2FLog%5B3%5D+%3D+3) seems to agree.

Comment: Webassign is not accepting my answer.

Comment: The answer is supposed to be 7.5385[something]. Try 7.539.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't make any mistake. Everything was perfect, great job! You used the following properties:

Step 1: $\rm\log_b(x)-\log_b(y)=\log_b{(x/y)}$
Step 2: $\rm\log_b(x)=c\iff x=b^{c}$ 
Step 3: $\rm x/y=c\iff x=cy$
Step 4: The distributive law.
Step 5: We can add the same thing to both sides of an equation. 
Step 6: $\rm cx=b\iff x=b/c$

I hope this helps. 
Best wishes, $\mathcal H$akim.